# RcppEigen package "#pragma clang diagnostic pop" warnings

Tags: r, rcpp

I am having some trouble when trying to use the `RcppEigen`package. I used the example posted [here](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/eigen-eigenvalues/). The function worked, but R generated a series of similar warnings (example as below).

```
In file included from example.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/nguy2338/Library/R/3.4/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigen.h:25:
In file included from /Users/nguy2338/Library/R/3.4/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30:
In file included from /Users/nguy2338/Library/R/3.4/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1:
In file included from /Users/nguy2338/Library/R/3.4/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:531:
/Users/nguy2338/Library/R/3.4/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:10:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

So, what do these warnings mean and how should I deal with these warnings?

Comment: I think this is actually harmless, but you might need to talk to RcppEigen and/or Eigen maintainers to find out?

Comment: see also: http://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/boost-and-rcppeigen-warnings-for-r-package-using-stan/3478/2 ; http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2018/02/13/#bh_1.66.0-1

Comment: You can suppress these warnings _locally_ by adding to `~/.R/Makevars` on your machine (and I often do as warnings are annoying); per the wisdom of the CRAN maintainers and their Policy you cannot suppress them at CRAN :-/

Comment: I added `PKG_CPPFLAGS = -Wno-unknown-pragmas` to my `Makevars` but I still see these warnings: am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is

```
#define EIGEN_PERMANENTLY_DISABLE_STUPID_WARNINGS
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
```

Comment: Or with -DEIGEN_PERMANENTLY_DISABLE_STUPID_WARNINGS in CXXFLAGS or similar.

Answer (score -2):

I wonder if there is inadvertently some code commented out here:
https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/blob/master/inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/DisableStupidWarnings.h#L41

which accounts for the mismatched `pop` here:
https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/blob/master/inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h#L13

The real warning it is trying to enable is `-Wconstant-logical-operand` which may be annoying, but not as annoying as this missing `push`.